How do we determine what small angle and small $x$ are for a simple pendulum to justify linear approximation?
Consider a simple pendulum consisting of a point-like mass $m$ attached to a massless string of length $L$ from a fixed support and constrained to move in a vertical plane.
Here is a picture of this

In terms of the angle $\theta$, the equation of motion is
$$\ddot{\theta}+\frac{g}{L}\sin{\theta}=0\tag{1}$$
In terms of the Cartesian coordinate $x$, I think we can also derive the differential equation
$$\frac{\ddot{x}(t)}{(L^2-x^2)^{1/2}}+\frac{x\dot{x}^2}{(L^2-x^2)^{3/2}}=-\frac{x}{L^2}g\tag{2}$$
based on the relationship $\sin{\theta}=\frac{x}{L}$ and Newton's 2nd law.
If $\theta$ is small then we can use $\sin{\theta}\approx \theta$ to obtain
$$\ddot{\theta}+\frac{g}{L}\theta=0\tag{3}$$
Similarly, if we assume that $x$ is small then it seems we can disregard $x^2$ in (2) and (I think, but I am not sure) we can also disregard $x\dot{x}^2$ in (2) thus obtaining (3) once more.
How do we determine what "small" means for $\theta$ and $x$?
In other words, how do we justify using linear approximations to (1) and (2)?
In addition, how do we justify disregarding $x\dot{x}^2$?

what you want is the linearization of an ODE. I have written about it in the following PhySE answer of mine: Issue expanding $\sin \theta$ about $\theta_{eq}$.

Link failed, at least for me. All I see is [this] with no clickable hyperlink @peek-a-boo

I cannot see any good reason to write Equation (2). As for how large a “small” amount can be, the larger it is the more error is introduced. How much error can you tolerate?

The $x\dot x^2$ term seems dubious.

peek-a-boo already gave a excellent link to a very technical answer (more technical than I could do myself), but as someone who did a lot of thinking on this when I first saw the pendulum approximation, I still want to add my two cents.
When we take $\sin{x} \approx x$, what we are really doing is dropping all the higher order terms in the taylor series for $\sin{x}$. This is because $\sin{x} = x - \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + \dots$. Like any approximation, dropping all these terms must add some ammount of error. In fact, we can go as far as to find an upper bound for this error term $R_{2}(x)$ fairly easily (for the derivation of this, google error term of taylor series):
$\vert R_{2}(x) \vert \leq \vert \frac{-\sin(c)}{3!}x^{3} \vert$
Where $c \in [0,x]$ is the value that maximizes $\vert -\sin(c) \vert$.
Now, if we assume $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ (reasonable for a "small angle" pendulumn, regardless of what exactly you call small, I think we can all agree a 90 degree oscilation is not included), it's clear $\vert -\sin(c) \vert = \sin(c)$ is maximized for $c \in [0,x]$ when $c=x$, since sine is increasing in this interval.
So, we have,
$R_{2}(x) \leq \frac{\sin{x}}{3!}x^{3}$
So it falls to you, as the one solving the problem, to decide what $x$ gives an small enough upper bound on the error term for you to be satisfied. The commonly accepted value is $x <10^{\circ} = \frac{\pi}{19}$. This value for $x$ gives the following error:
$R_{2}(x) \leq \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{19})}{3!}*(\frac{\pi}{19})^{3}\approx 0.000124008976194902629$
It's not as clear how to find an error bound from the cartesian form of the ODE using elementary methods, so you will need to refer to peek-a-boo's link for that.
